# Checking if ArrayList doesn't contain a String in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

I have two ArrayLists: myList and myList1. myList contains strings, such as "aaa 111", "bbb 222", and "aaa 333". myList1 is currently empty, but I want to populate it by seeing if myList1 doesn't contain part of the string from myList. The "symbol" variable, for example, is "aaa". The "num" variable is "111". The "s" variable is symbol + num. So the "s" variable is "aaa 111". For this code, aaa 111 would be added to myList1 (because myList1 doesn't contain aaa), bbb 222 would be added to myList1 (because myList1 doesn't contain bbb; at this point it just contains aaa 111), aaa 333 should not be added to myList1 and should go to the else statement (because myList1 already contains aaa (because of aaa 111)). However, when I run my code it adds all three strings to myList1.

```
if (!myList1.contains(symbol)) {            
     myList1.add(s);
} else {
     //do something
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you simply give an input and an expected output. That would say more than the whole description of the problem

Comment: Split the element values of myList using `String.split(" ")` then add the individual symbols to a Hash Set.  As you iterate through myList split the values, check if they are in the Hash Set, if not add them to myList1 and to the Hash Set.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in comments, you would need to split the string to extract symbol from it and maintain a Set of already added symbols. While adding you can check whether current element's symbol is inside already added symbols or not:

```java
private static List<String> createDistinctSymbolList(List<String> myList) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> addedSymbols = new HashSet<>();

    for (String s : myList) {
        String currentSymbol = getSymbol(s);
        if (!addedSymbols.contains(currentSymbol)) {
            result.add(s);
        }
        addedSymbols.add(getSymbol(s));
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getSymbol(String str) {
    String[] parts = str.split(" ");
    return parts[0];
}
```

I tested it with this code:

```java
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("aaa 111");
myList.add("bbb 222");
myList.add("aaa 333");

List<String> distincAAA = createDistinctSymbolList(myList);
distincAAA.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints out this output:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("aaa 111");
myList.add("bbb 222");
myList.add("aaa 333");

List<String> distincAAA = createDistinctSymbolList(myList);
distincAAA.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple of years since I've done java programming, so forgive any syntax errors

```
HashSet symbolSet = new HashSet();
for (String n: myList) {
  String[] symbols = n.split(" ");
  boolean found = false;
  for (String sym: symbols) {
    if (symbolSet.contains(sym))
       found = true;
   }
}
   if (!found) {
     myList1.add(n);
     for (String sym: symbols) {
       symbolSet.add(sym);
     }
   }
 
}
```